# ConfigureAwait(false) with ADO.Net SQLConnection object

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, async-await, configureawait

I have started using `ConfigureAwait(false)` with all the async sql objects.

```
connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**But my concern is, Will there be any implications with this approach?.**

As this will run on a thread pool which is a separate thread from which it got originated i am not sure about the consequences if we dont run it on a single thread.

Our application is wcf service which will process the 1000's of records parallel.

If some one helps to identity the business scenarios where it could be problem that would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't know how or why to use it, why are you sticking it on everything?

Comment: thinking aloud here (I've never investigated), but I suspect that *ambient transactions* (aka `TransactionScope`) would be pretty scuppered if you used `ConfigureAwat(false)` - but: I haven't actually checked whether they work with `aysnc` **without** `ConfigureAwait(false)` :)

Comment: I have chosen it because it will give the performance boost on multi core environment

Comment: @MarcGravell there is special [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn261473(v=vs.110).aspx) (starting for .NET 4.5.1) which allows you to tell `TransactionScope` if it should flow through async continuations or not. But if you don't use this constructor (most cases as of now I think) - it won't flow. I've answered a question couple of days ago when OP used `TransactionScope` with await without this constructor, which led to surprising results...

Comment: i actually least bother about c# TransactionScope object which i am not using. I am following all stored procedure calls which contains SQL Transaction's with in Store Proc's

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a general rule, as long as a region of async operations are *self contained and independent*, you should be fine using `ConfigureAwait(false)` - and indeed doing so can be important to reduce overheads and bottlenecks. The library code *usually doesn't need to know about* the call-context. However, *consuming* code (such as winforms, MVC, etc) usually needs to get back to *the appropriate context*, so **should not** use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. For example:

```
async Task SomeUXCodeAsync() {
    var data = await GetSomeDataAsync(); // note no ConfigureAwait(false)
    // not shown: use "data"
}
async Task<Foo> GetSomeDataAsync() {
    using(var conn = CreateConnection()) {
        await conn.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        ...
        int result = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        ...
        return ...
    }
}
```

The above scenario is pretty typical and common, *but* it is more complex than that - the `TransactionScope` example from the comments touches on examples where the data related code *might* need to know about the call context, for example. But nuance aside: as long as the *consuming* code remembers not to ignore the call context, you'll usually end up back at the right place. Sorry this is a little vague and woolly, but : sadly that's kinda the case *generally* for the call-context.